# Command prompt in Windows and Linux -- What is their language called?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

When the command prompt is being used to do networking, searching, setting parameters in the localhost, etc, what is the language used to enter in the command prompt in Windows?  How about in Linux?  Is there a name for it?  It is it DOS or unix? Or is it just a bunch of commands utilized within the OS that have no name?

Thank you.

Comment: **See Also**: [What is the “language” of a .bat batch file on windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1057096/180163)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Windows, when you open a command prompt, almost always the program that is running is `cmd.exe`.  It's an enhanced NT derivative of the old DOS-based `command.com`, which is in turn has similarites with the even older CP/M `CCP` command interpreter.

In Linux, as @Griffin mentions, usually you are running `bash` in some sort of terminal emulator if you are using it in a graphical environment.  (which can vary widely depending on your distro and desktop environment).  This stands for "Bourne Again SHell" because it's an extended version of an earlier "Bourne" shell (`sh`) that's been standard on Unix for a long time.  There's other "alternative" shells in common use such as `csh`, `ksh`, and `tcsh`.

The Windows `cmd.exe` can be considered a shell as well (as can `explorer.exe`).

Both the Windows command prompt and all Unix shells have several "built-ins", or commands that are handled entirely within the shell.  This includes some basic commands (such as `cd`) and many conditional commands and operators that control script flow if a batch file of commands are executed.

However, in both Linux and Windows, the great majority of "commands" that do useful things are in fact external programs that are "called" by the the shell.  And that is the primary purpose of a shell, to enable an operator to start programs with specifying arguments for those programs.  It's not really strictly a programming language, it's just a framework for launching programs.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a "language" really.  It's simply the [Command-Line Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (CLI) for that particular operating system.

The commands and syntax are chosen and defined by the operating system creators.

There are various [scripting languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) (some more popular that others, depending on the operating system, etc.) that are commonly used with in conjunction with a CLI to perform batches of tasks.

BTW the term "Command Prompt" refers to the actual bit of text that signifies where you are to enter your next command in the CLI. (ie: `C:\>` or `#`, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses batch. The most popular language in Linux is bash, but there are alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

MS Windows Shell Command Language?

In comparison to

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, or any other Unix-based system, they call it shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

With Linux, "**shell script**" languages are called that, or by the name of the shell, most commonly "**bash**".

There is quite a variety of terminology used for the command shell language on Windows, due in part to name changes in the platforms. Some options that are used:

- **CMD** or **Command Shell** (like the language of the Bash interpreter is called Bash)
- **Batch** (related to the .bat batch file type)
- DOS Batch (perhaps "historical" but not necessarily invalid)
- MS-DOS Batch Scripting Language
- Windows Commands
- Batch Commands

Some of these might be more appropriate when referring to the versions that come with specific versions of Windows.