# What is the "language" of a .bat batch file on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

When Windows is running one of these programs what is the actual language being used? Is it C++ or something else?

Comment: @FrankThomas [shellcode is already a specific term meaning a bit of machine code used to exploit a security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode). It's never used to refer to generic shell scripts or batch files.

Comment: **See Also**: [Command prompt in Windows and Linux -- What is their language called?](https://superuser.com/q/349481/180163)

Answer (score 19):

A [.bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file is a DOS/Windows shell script executed by the DOS/Windows command interpreter.  When a batch script is saved to a `.bat` file, it is just called a *"batch file"*.

The language is simply `batch script`.  It is not a high level language like C++, but a simple interpreted scripting language.

Some consider batch files to be limited in functionality.  Microsoft has released [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), which is a powerful, yet complex, scripting language.

Comment: Batch files are not limited in functionality. You can do almost anything with them.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra batch files are *extremely* limited.  they cannot do anything close to a full programming language, or other scripting languages.

Comment: @ Keltari, the Windwos batch language is Turing-complete. Here, for example, is a *Brainfuck* [interpreter](https://github.com/YoYoYonnY/Brainfuck-In-Batch/blob/master/interpreter.bat) in this language.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes known as the MS-DOS Batch File Language, or simply batch commands: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722477.aspx. It is merely the encapsulation (in a file) of a series of commands, most of which could also be executed on the command line itself (at the prompt, outside of the batch file).

Answer (score 0):

Windows script is what's being used, it doesn't get translated to another language it's just telling Windows explicitly what to do.

Comment: Batch files came about before Windows in the DOS era, so the term Windows script is inaccurate. Also, there are a lot of Windows scripting languages: PowerShell's, VBScript, JScript, batch files.